# What is the ultimate goal of the Sith?

Tags: character, star-wars

Do the Sith want to rule the galaxy? Is that the only reason they want power?

It doesn't make sense if they are doing it to be rich, or they will capture all that there is and destroy the galaxy.

So what is the ultimate goal of the Sith?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that, you must first know the [Code of the Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Code_of_the_Sith):

> Peace is a lie. There is only Passion.
>
> Through Passion I gain Strength.
>
> Through Strength I gain Power.
>
> Through Power I gain Victory.
>
> Through Victory my chains are Broken.
>
> The Force shall free me.

Their code is more about personal freedom and power. They don't want to work within rules set by others, and want full freedom to do whatever they feel like doing. That's why they transformed the Galactic Republic into the Galactic Empire, so that they can do whatever they want.

There is debate as to whether the Code of the Sith is canon now or not, but it's safe to assume it is. Because the line

> Through victory, my chains are broken.

did appear in [Star Wars: The Clone Wars S04 E21](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-wars-the-clone-wars&episode=s04e21).

Comment: Do remember that the Code of the Sith has its origins in noncanon video game Knights of the Old Republic and hasn't appeared in totality in any Disney-era pieces (and certainly never in any Lucasian movies).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70611/discussion-between-edlothiad-and-ankit-sharma).

Comment: @Exal as I've linked to ankit in the chat above, you can find a canon source [here](https://i.imgur.com/klKTVN0.jpg). It may be interesting to note a lot of the KOTOR stuff is [entering canon](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWarsEU/comments/61f7g9/most_if_not_all_eu_the_old_republic_elements/).

Comment: @Edlothiad  Cool cool.  Rest assured I didn't mean to start up the argument that occurred.  Now if only Revan was a woman, everything would be just about right with the world.

Answer (score -2):

Because someone taken their teddy bear when they were 5.

Sith are fuelled with all emotions (they should be keep in a glass cage). Because they can. So their emotions run their motives. Ben want his parents to love him and his uncle to say he's good at school. 
Skookem or Smoke or whatever his name is want to play with people like a puppeteer.

Sith's have needs and urges. And the best way to fill them is to have unlimited power because then no one will tell you "no". Well, technically they will but you can kill them and don't waste time explaining why you did it. So you have more time for killing another one.

It's like having a straight flat road with a 40 mph limit. Wouldn't you like to go 60 and if someone catch to not get and pay ticket?